# How does Microsoft Azure extension sorted?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Added many extensions from a marketplace such as [Calendar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar) and it is visible under Boards on the left pane. However, how do I sort them when there are many extensions added to my Boards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we are not able to change the order of any installed extension or build-in feature with boards under web portal UI.

[image]

You could **submit a feature request** in our official [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea).

Beside, not all extensions are installed in this specific place(actually only a little), it's based on the developer of the extension. You could check more detail info  from here-- [Develop a web extension for Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

Not every extension adds a custom work hub as Calendar does. In fact, I suspect only a few of them do. Other extensions enrich other areas with new functionality. Often only build tasks are brought in.

There's definitely no `filter` option under the *Boards* hub. If there are plenty of custom work hubs, you'll have to scroll through those.

On the other hand, the `Manage Extensions` view has a nice and convenient *Filter* option:

[image: Filter extensions]